# Getting device information

Tags: ios, objective-c

Im building a personalized news app(ios will talk with a backend api). When a new user usesthe app, I would like to get her device information in order to provide her with relevant news without her participation. To do this it would be nice to have the possibility to get the categories of the appsthe user has installed in her device, location, device id ...

I have no experience with iOS. I have been reading some posts and information but I am pretty confused about what kind of information I can actually get.

Comment: I, as a user, would be concerned about what kind of information you could actually get.

Comment: Apple will reject straight away if you are sending information about the user/device without the knowledge of the user so "without her participation" would be very bad.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to look at the [UIDevice class](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html) reference to get started determining non-[personnally identifiable information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personally_identifiable_information).

You won't be able to do things like automatically check what other apps they have installed as that would constitute a massive breach of security and your app would be rejected by Apple without a second thought.

Comment: Ok, it's now clear that what I thought cannot be done. Is there a way to get the installed apps if I ask the user for permission?

Answer (score 0):

You can get some information about which apps the user might have installed by asking which URLs the device can open (using UIApplication canOpenURL: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/canOpenURL:)

In one app I wanted to know if the user had the YouTube app installed and used this:

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"youtube://foo"]]

The YouTube app is setup to handle urls starting with youtube:// so if the device can handle it then it suggests, though doesn't necessarily mean, that they have the YouTube app installs. It's possible for other apps to claim they handle the youtube:// links too so it's not 100% accurate but may be close enough.

How you figure out what links each app you're interested in handles (and bear in mind that some apps won't handle any URLs like this) I don't know....

Answer (score 0):

There is a 3rd party library that uses 3 types of methods to check what other apps are installed on the device

It's called [iHasApp](https://www.ihasapp.com/) and it's being used by a lot of developers that successfully submitted apps to the App Store.

Apple would prefer for you to ask for permission first but since these methods are legal (on an app submission point of view) but do not require a user to give the app permission.

A good way to ask them for permission is to give them an incentive to do so. You pop an alert and explain the reason why you need this info and what you will do with it.

Comment: "iHasApp is no longer App Store compliant. It will be shutdown on January 2016" - Daniel Amitay.